# Mixing Up an Initializer and a Constructor Body in Dart

Tags: dart, constructor, initializer

I know that you can initialize `final` variables in a class with something like:

```dart
class A {
  final num x;
  final num y;
  final num d;

  A(this.x, this.y): 
    d = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2));
}
```

And you can create regular variables inside a constructor like this:

```dart
class A {
  String z;

  A(){
    z = 'hello';
  }
}
```

But how do you mix both? Is it possible? What is the syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply continue with the constructor right after the initializer, but, since you're going to use curly brackets (`{}`), you shouldn't use the semi-colon (`;`):

```dart
class A {
  final num x;
  final num y;
  final num d;
  String z;

  A(this.x, this.y) 
    : d = sqrt(pow(x, 2) + pow(y, 2))
  {
    z = 'hello';
  }
}
```